# Can I call a static method from outside a class without initializing the class?

Tags: python, static-methods

```
class BaseIndicesLinker:

    def __init__(
        self,
        date: int)

    @staticmethod
    def some_static_function(i: int):
        return datetime.datetime(...)



def retrieve_index_codes_from_index_objects(session, date):

    # converting date to expected datetime format
    datetime = some_static_function(date)

    return all_index_codes
```

The above doesn't work, because `some_static_function` is 'not defined'.

So I suppose my question is, is it possible to call on the static function without initializing the class `BaseIndicesLinker`?

Comment: Would @classmethod be a better use case here?

Comment: I agree with phix

Comment: If it's a static method, you should probably call it this way: `BaseIndicesLinker.some_static_function(date)`. Also, what do you mean by "*without initializing the class*"?

Comment: `BaseIndicesLinker.some_static_function(1)` does not call `__init__()`. If that is what you are asking.  You could always do `fn = BaseIndicesLinker.some_static_function` and call `fn()` as well if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call a `static` method without initializing the class. you just need to use the `class name` followed by the `method name`.

```
datetime = BaseIndicesLinker.some_static_function(date)
```